# Replacing a character with other in java

Tags: java, replace, character

Dear stackoverflow members,
I have a small problem,

I want to replace some characters in my string with other in java, and my code to do it is as follow,

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
String str =  new GenericResource_JerseyClient().getlist();
    String [] temp = null;
    temp = str.split(",");
     temp[1]=temp[1].replaceAll("'", "");
    temp[1]=temp[1].replaceAll(" ", "");
    temp[1]=temp[1].replace("[", "");
    temp[1]=temp[1].replace("]", "");

     for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++)
     {
         jComboBox1.addItem(temp[i]);
     }        // TODO add your handling code here:      // TODO add your handling code here:
                // TODO add your handling code here
    }
```

As it can be seen from the above code i replace "'","[","]",and empty space with nothing.
As it can be also seen from the code that i split the string into two. In the part of string after , the code works well but the part of string before , the code doesn't seem to work properly.
i have also attached a copy of the dropdown list output in the client side.

Any help would be very much appreciated on how to remove [ and ' from the string.

Cheers.[image: Client side output with [ and ']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perform all your replacements BEFORE splitting the string. This is better than executing the same code in a loop.

For example:

```
String cleanString = str.replace("'", "").replace(" ", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
String[] temp = cleanString.split(",");
for(int i = 0; i < temp.length ; i++) {
    jComboBox1.addItem(temp[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're only performing replacements on `temp[1]` - whereas the problem appears to be in the *first* item shown in the dropdown, which is presumably the data from `temp[0]`.

I suspect you should just extract the removal code into a separate method, and call it in your loop:

```
for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++)
{
    jComboBox1.addItem(removeUnwantedCharacters(temp[i]));
}
```

Additionally, I would *strongly* recommend that you use `replace` rather than `replaceAll` for any case where you *don't* explicitly want regular expression pattern matching. It can be very confusing to have code such as:

```
foo = foo.replaceAll(".", "");
```

which *looks* like it's removing dots, but will *actually* remove all characters, as the "." is treated as a regular expression...

Comment: When I see your name, I instinctively go to the upvote button :D .

Answer (score 1):

well, you performing replace only in item with index 1 (the second one). But then adding to the combo all of them (two, actually). Try:

```
for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++){
    temp[i]=temp[i].replaceAll("'", "");
    temp[i]=temp[i].replaceAll(" ", "");
    temp[i]=temp[i].replace("[", "");
    temp[i]=temp[i].replace("]", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Common problem.

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532905/string-replace-in-java-me-double-space) code meets your requirements.

Comment: @Kishorepandey: I can't see how that actually addresses your issue, which is that you were only fixing *one* string, rather than all of them.

Comment: @jon skeet i tried dogbane's method to first replace the characters and then to split them and it worked.

Comment: @Kishorepandey: So why did you accept *this* answer rather than dogbane's?

Comment: @jon skeet i am sorry, i was not knowing that, i changed it now!! thanks for reminding!!

Answer (score 1):

You are only doing the replacing on the temp[1] which is the second part of the string. You need to do in temp[0] as well.  It is better to create a function that takes a string and does the replacements and call it on both temp[0] and temp[1]. You can also look at using a regular expression to replace all characters at once instead of doing it one at a time.

```
String [] temp = String.split(",")

for (int i = 0;i<temp.length;i++) {
   temp[i] = replaceSpecialChars(temp[i]);
}

public String replaceSpecialChars(String input) {
// add your replacement logic here
return input
}
```